# MySQL - Search exact word match and ordering

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

**I have the following in my table**

Best Leonardo DiCaprio Movies

Best Samuel L Jackson Movies

Best Edward Norton Movies

Animated Movies

Indian Movies

Indian Recipes

Indian Market

Movies

And I want to search for "Indian Movies" the result should be like

**Indian Movies**

**Indian** Recipes
**Indian** Market

**Movies**
Best Leonardo DiCaprio **Movies**

Best Samuel L Jackson **Movies**

Best Edward Norton **Movies**

Animated **Movies**

How can i write an SQL query for this.

Comment: search for `FULLTEXT SEARCH`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Full TEXT index search here.

But Full-text searches are supported for `MyISAM` tables only.

Add `FULLTEXT` index to your column, then use the following query:

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE MATCH (column_name)
AGAINST ('Indian Movies' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

**Results:**

> **Indian** Movies
>   **Indian** Recipes **Indian** Market
>   **Movies** Best Leonardo DiCaprio **Movies**
>   Best Samuel L Jackson **Movies**
>   Best Edward Norton **Movies**
>   Animated **Movies**

Comment: You might want to mention how to _"Add `FULLTEXT` index to your column"_ (Instead of someone else just editing it in)

Answer (score -1):

you need to split the string...

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `title` LIKE '%".$query1."%'") or die(mysql_error());

// movie is the name of our table

// '%$query%' and '%$query1%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Indian Movies
// it will match "Indian Movies", "Indian Recipes Indian Market", "Movies Best Leonardo DiCaprio Movies", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
```

Comment: Also want to sort the results

Comment: its easy @Ayyappadhas you just add "ORDER BY title DESC" at the end it will sort in descending order and leave it for ascending (default)

Comment: but its an alphabetical sorting only. I want to show the results with "Indian Movies" first, then results with "Indian" then result with "Movies" and so on.